# Sed command used to delete a specific line from File using line number not deleting when used with variable

Tags: sed

I am using this command with variables

```
sed '/${LN_NM}/d' file.txt
```

I am using it to delete a line from `file.txt`.
But when this command is used without the variable it works fine.

Comment: Variables are not expanded in single quotes, use double quotes.

Comment: Apart from using double quotes you also need to do away with the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

`/regular expression/d` will delete lines that match that regular expression (So if `$LN_NUM` is just a number like 5 or 18, every line with that number somewhere in it). If you want to instead delete the given line number:

```
sed "${LN_NM}d" file.txt
```

If you want to save the file after deleting that line from it, use `ed`, not `sed`:

```
ed -s file.txt <<EOF
${LN_NM}d
w
EOF
```

Comment: You can use `sed -i` to edit the file in place, instead of using `ed`.

Comment: @DavidConrad I can't recommend that; `sed -i` is non standard and different implementations that support it as an extension have different behaviors - OS X `sed`, for example, requires it to have an argument, while one is optional with GNU `sed`. Better to stay within POSIX especially when the asker doesn't say what OS they're using.

Comment: Fair enough. I upvoted you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As @plumo already mentioned, variables wont get substituted while using `'` (single quotes)

Change your command by using `"` double-quotes, which should do the trick.

`sed "/${LN_NM}d/" file.txt`

Comment: That will delete lines containing the number in `$LN_NUM`, not the exact line number...

Comment: sorry, I misstyped the regular expression. I've updated the answer to correct it.

Comment: Uh, no. That won't even delete lines matching the regular expression, much less the line with the specific line number. Try it before you post.